# 「独自のサーバーフレームワークで Nuxt をプログラムにより使用」の意味

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

[このページ](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/ja/guide/setup.html#%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)を見ながら`Nuxt`で`TypeScript`を使うための設定を行っていたのですが

下記の文章の意味がわかりませんでした。

> WARNING
>
> 独自のサーバーフレームワークで Nuxt をプログラムにより使用している場合、ビルドを行う前に Nuxt
>   の準備ができるまで待機する必要があることに注意してください：

「独自のサーバーフレームワークで Nuxt をプログラムにより使用」とは具体的にどのような状態を指すのでしょうか？

何か実例などをあれば教えて下さい。

英語版では以下のようになっていました。

> If you are using Nuxt programmatically with a custom server framework,
>   note that you will need to ensure that you wait for Nuxt to be ready
>   before building:

Comment: create-nuxt-app で アプリのテンプレートを作成するときに Use a custom server framework ? みたいな質問あったと思うんですが、それのことかと。express とか。

Comment: なるほど、作成時の選択でデフォルト以外を選択してたときのことを刺してたんですね。ありがとうございます。